# Automate a user assignment to a specific app role within an application

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I'm automating an app setup and having registered an applicatioin with `az ad app create --app-roles` with the manifest:

```
[{
    "allowedMemberTypes": [
      "User",
      "Application"
    ],
    "description": "Read items",
    "displayName": "Reader",
    "isEnabled": "true",
    "value": "items/r"
}]
```

I'm trying to figure a way to assign above mentioned `Reader` to a principal without PowerShell's [New-AzureADUserAppRoleAssignment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/new-azureaduserapproleassignment?view=azureadps-2.0) and coming up empty. I'd take ARM template, .NET SDK or `az` CLI way of doing it, but none seem to support it.

Not interested in the portal/ui as I'm trying to script this, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [az cli rest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/reference-index?view=azure-cli-latest#az-rest) to assign a custom app role to a principal via Azure AD Graph Rest API :

```
az rest --method post --uri "https://graph.windows.net/<your tenant ID>/servicePrincipals/<your principle object Id>/appRoleAssignments?api-version=1.6" --body "{\"id\":\"<your custom role app ID>\",\"principalId\":\"<your principle object Id>\",\"resourceId\":\"<your app object id>\"}" --headers "Authorization=Bearer <access token>"
```

You can get access token via [az account get access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/account?view=azure-cli-latest#az-account-get-access-token) :

```
az account get-access-token --resource "https://graph.windows.net"
```

Test request on Azure cli : 
[image]

Result, as you can see the role has been assigned to principle successfully  : 
[image]

Comment: I think this answer might be useful to me, except I want to add a user rather than a service principal. The only examples I can find use the new Microsoft Graph API and I don't know how to scope a POST request to my tenant.  Is there some reference that will help me translate this request to add a role for a user?